# Spring resource handling : NOT FOUND

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have **WEB-INF** folder like this : 
[image]

And in my **webconfig.java** :

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {

    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");

    return resolver;
}



@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
    .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");

}
```

and **in my view** i'm calling the resources like this [in '**index.html**'] :

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/lib/angular-toastr.css" >
```

but then the resources are not loaded and I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

I'm accessing my index page with my controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/myShellPage")
public String ShellPage() {

    return "index";
}
```

and the **URL** of the **index page** is : `http://localhost:8080/gestionprojet/transtu/myShellPage?#/`

and the **URL** of **the resources generating the error** is : `http://localhost:8080/gestionprojet/transtu/$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/resources/lib/angular-toastr.css`

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I think the problem comes from `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` cause I'm doing it in a html file instead of jsp file. Any alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

try this it should work

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
          .addResourceLocations("(/resources/");    
    }
```

Static resource

`<link href="<c:url value="/resources/lib/angular-toastr.css" />" rel="stylesheet">`